# Is this a true error, or am I just misinterpreting what is happening?

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, pycharm, kali-linux

I'm attempting to make a program in Pycharm in Kali Linux that will, in order:

- Disabled the interface
- Run `airmon-ng check kill`
- Run `iwconfig interface mode monitor`
- Run `ifconfig interface up`
- Print if it worked or not

I'm using some of the code I used to make a MAC address changer for a Udemy course I'm taking, but I'm not sure if it is making the process faster or just more confusing. I think I understand most of it, but I'm a bit hung up.

After I run it, it appears to have worked. Iwconfig says that it's on monitor mode, and ifconfig says that it's up. However, when it finishes, it gives me the error message I programmed into it. Is it really showing an error?

I've tried re-purposing the code I used to make a MAC address changer to try and save some time, and I tried programming an `if is true` statement at the end to test if monitor mode is on.

monitor_mode code:

```
monitor_mode(options.interface)



...

def monitor_mode(interface):
    print("[+] Activating Monitor Mode for " + interface)

    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
    subprocess.call(["airmon-ng", "check", "kill"])
    subprocess.call(["iwconfig", interface, "mode", "monitor"])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])


options = get_arguments()

monitor_mode(options.interface)

if monitor_mode is True:
    print("[+] Interface switched to monitor mode.")
else:
    print("[-] Error.")
```

Original mac_changer code:

```
def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("[+] Changing MAC Address for " + interface + " to " + new_mac)

    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])

def get_current_mac(interface):
    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", interface])
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)

    if mac_address_search_result:
        return mac_address_search_result.group(0)
    else:
        print("[-] Could not read MAC address.")

options = get_arguments()

current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
print("Current MAC = " + str(current_mac))

change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)

current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
if current_mac == options.new_mac:
    print("[+] MAC successfully changed to " + current_mac)
else:
    print("[-] MAC unchanged.")
```

I expected for my monitor_mode program to shut down `wlan0`, run `airmon-ng check kill`, turn wlan0 on monitor mode via `iwconfig`, then bring `wlan0` back up.

Instead it did just that, but it printed the error message I gave it, though nothing else about it suggests that it really was a failure.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

- the test `if monitor_mode is True` will always return `False`, since `monitor_mode` is a **function**, and thus you are comparing a function with `True`
- instead, you should be comparing the return value of `monitor_mode` as something like:

```
      if monitor_mode(options.interface):
          print("[+] Interface switched to monitor mode.")
      else:
          print("[-] Error.")
```

However this will not work until you alter the `monitor_mode` function to actually **return** a useful value indicating its success or otherwise ... currently it **always** returns a `False` value.